# Why is the left bracket [ darker than the right bracket ] in equations?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I was writing up some formulas with concentrations on Chemistry.SE, and the left brace is noticeably darker than the right brace. I replaced them with `\lvert` and `\rvert`, but it is harder to write. is there a reason for this?

Example:

```
$$ K_{eq} = \frac{[\ce{NO}][\ce{O2}]}{[\ce{NO2}]^2} $$
```

Here's a link to [the question on Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/why-are-equilibrium-constants-unitless), where you can see the bracing difference, and [my answer below](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/why-are-equilibrium-constants-unitless/1140#1140) where I substituted `\lvert` and `\rvert`.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the braces. Perhaps it is just a browser/viewer effect?

Comment: I can get them to look equivalent if I zoom into the page some. Try using ctrl+'+' and ctrl+'-' to view them at varying zoom levels. Perhaps this is a browser issue.

Comment: Also, can I not access math mode on tex.SE? Are different libraries enabled based on the site?

Comment: This is a rendering issue in MathJax for that specific font style - note the difference when typesetting `${\scriptscriptstyle [x]}\ {\scriptstyle [x]}\ [x]$`. TeX.SE does not support MathJax, since it's about the code as well, not just the display/output. As such, being MathJax related, I think this is off-topic.

Comment: Where are MathJax related questions on-topic? Math.SE?

Comment: @Ehryk no; zooming in or out I still don't see any difference (using Chrome). Seems like a browser issue.

Comment: @Ehryk: It could fit on either [so] or [su], if you read their respective FAQs ([SO/faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), [SU/faq](http://superuser.com/faq)).